# can remote config of Firebase handle when I add a new class or a new method?

Tags: android, firebase

I have an android app, and I want to know if when I release the app and want to add some more feature to my app can remote config handle this situation too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using firebase We can only change existing varibles/Constants only but we cannot add new classes

Comment: so is there a better way for creating new class or method ?

Comment: @abdulkhaliqseddiqi when apk was generated all classes will turn into dexfiles so we cannot add or remove classes once an apk is generated